# Search through big list of lists

Tags: python, list, search

I have a list of coordinates (x and y like this: `coordinates = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]` but much bigger) that updates every iteration (appends new list). So I need to search if `current_pos` (which is also a list like `[4, 10]`) is in `coordinates`. Here is my snippet of code:

```
for move in range(len(movement_string)):
    # ...
    # code changes current_pos
    # ...
    if current_pos in coordinates:
        fail = True
        failed_move = move + 1
        break
    else:
        coordinates.append(current_pos)
```

It works pretty fine with small lists, but it takes too long time for big lists with 10.000 - 1.000.000 items. I think the problem is in searching through list, because as it becomes bigger, the time it uses becomes also longer.

Comment: If the order of `coordinates` does not matter then it can be a set of tuples instead of list of lists. Then `current_pos in coordinates` becomes an O(1) operation instead of O(n)

Comment: What is `movement_string`?

Comment: @Austin it just a string like `DDRRRULLDL` that says which direction to turn and this changes `current_pos`.

Comment: @DeepSpace yes, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just turn `coordinates` to a `set`

```
coordinates = set()
```

and make `current_pos` a `tuple` so you can insert it in a `set`. At some point:

```
current_pos = tuple(current_pos)
```

then your loop becomes:

```
for move in range(len(movement_string)):
    # ...
    # code changes current_pos
    # ...
    if current_pos in coordinates:
        fail = True
        failed_move = move + 1
        break
    else:
        coordinates.add(current_pos)
```

and that's it. You get `O(1)` lookup so it doesn't depend on the length of the `coordinates` set.

If order matters, just creates a `set` as above and keep the `list` too to append to if not already seen (widely covered like here: [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order)).

Comment: I had the same idea exactly. Was worth turning it into an answer